# Floor function for power of 2

Tags: ceiling-and-floor-functions

I am confused about this. Which one is true?

$2^{\lfloor{2log_2(x)}\rfloor} =\lfloor{x^2}\rfloor$

or

$2^{\lfloor{2log_2(x)}\rfloor} =\lfloor{x}\rfloor^2$

Comment: Assuming that one of them must be true, you can just substitute $x = \sqrt{2}$

Comment: what about $x=\frac 12$ ?